# Add onItemSelected in tabs from java

Tags: java, android

I have a ArrayList, and just one tab in my XML, i add tabs in java class using name.addTab()... But i need to know how to change my image and listview if i click in the other tabs, is like to change the content in the same fragment when i click in the tabs...

```
final String[] hotWaterReadList = {"28 / 02 / 2020","28 / 01 / 2020","28 / 12 / 2019","28 / 11 / 2019","28 / 10 / 2019","28 / 09 / 2019","28 / 08 / 2019","28 / 07 / 2019","28 / 06 / 2019","28 / 05 / 2019","28 / 04 / 2019",
            "28 / 03 / 2019","28 / 02 / 2019","28 / 01 / 2019"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hotWaterReadList){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hotwater_item, parent,false);
            }

            TextView hotItemText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_hotWater);
            ImageView imageHotWater = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconhot);

            hotItemText.setText(hotWaterReadList[position]);
            imageHotWater.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_agua_caliente);
            return convertView;
        }
    };

    tabsReads.addTab(tabsReads.newTab().setText("Agua fría"));
    tabsReads.addTab(tabsReads.newTab().setText("Agua caliente"));
    hotWaterList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the problem is that i don´t have id in the tabs because aren´t from xml... maybe an if? or switch? help me please, thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. add as many tabs as you want
2. Then you just need to add an onTabSelectedListner e.g.

   tabsReads.addOnTabSelectedListener
           (new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

       }
   });
   ```
3. now every time you select a tab you just have to change the content of the ListView inside onTabSelected you can pass a new string array as data set or
   you just can set a new adapter with new data on that ListView.

Comment: i did before read your answer but thank you so much, it was perfect